# question on the output of a java snippet

Tags: java

The following snippet gives output as

> Sup.field=0, Sup.getField()=1

I do not understand why Sup.getField() does not get 0 instead?

```
class Super {
   public int field = 0;
   public int getField(){return field;}
}

class Sub extends Super {
   public int field  = 1;
   public int getField() {return field;}
   public int get SuperField() { return  super.field;}  
}

public class FieldAccess{
   public static void main(String[] args){
   Super Sup = new Sub();
   System.out.println("Sup.field ="+Sup.field + ",Sup.getField()"+Sup.getField());
  }
}
```

Comment: if you change the definition type to `Sub sup = new Sub()` then the output will be 1, 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Instance variables are not overridden ..they are merely hidden**. Referring to the `super.field` refers to the actual field in the super class based on reference.

Methods are overridden and the call is made based on the object type at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

All methods in java are virtual (c# term) or polymorphic by default and that's what you are seeing (the class fields are not).

When you call `sup.field`, it accesses field `field` in class `Super` but when you call `getField()` it calls the `getField()` method in class `Sub` because the instance is of type `Sub`.

[This page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) has a good definition and some examples of polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

This is because,

```
Super Sup = new Sub();
```

This means that the object holds instance of the derived class object. That means, in the object memory the value of field is 1 and not 0.

So, when you run

```
Sup.getfield()
```

it runs the method of the derived class which resides in the memory that is tagged as memory for the Super class.

So, Its the difference in what it is and what it seems like.

Answer (score 0):

What you are witnessing is the effect of method *overriding* (not to be confused with method *overloading*).
Even though the reference type is of type Super(), the actual method to call is resolved when the program is executing (runtime polymorphism), and because the getField() method is overridden by the subclass, that is what gets called and hence returns the value in the subtype. If you want 0 in both cases, change your instantiation to `Super Sup = new Sub();`